# No article with plural - possible meanings

Tags: articles

Please, tell me the meaning of the sentence:

"There are books on my table. Books on my table are good."

Does it mean:

1) All the books that are now on my table are good?

2) All the books I put on my table automatically become good?

3) All or some of the books that are now on my table are good?

Thanks!)

Comment: None of the above. A bare noun like this is a kind of class signifier.

Comment: "Guests always make for happy Sundays." and of course, "Guests are like fish ..." :)

Answer (score 2):

*There are books on my table* is fine, but *Books on my table are good* is idiomatic English only in circumstances which appear to be excluded by the first sentence.

Bare *Books on my table are good* implies a partition of the set of all books into two subsets. All of those which are on your table, and *only* those which are on your table, are warranted by you to be good; books which are not on your table may be good or may not be.

But the preceding sentence *There are books on my table*, in the absence of further context, restricts the current discourse to those particular books. Since they have already been identified, they are determinate, and if you want to characterize them as good books you must employ a definite determiner: ***The*** books on my table or ***All*** books ... or ***Those*** books ... or something of that sort.

There is also the possibility that you wish to convey your satisfaction at having books on your table. In that case you should say:

> Books on my table **is** good.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! :) I thought that usage of no article before plurals can mean that we are going to list just some of the things.. Like here: "Reasons of it are..." - We're going to list some of the reasons. But what I figure out from your answer, is that no article before plural means ALL of that kind. So, why "Books on my table are good" tells that all the books on my table are good, but "Reasons of it are" has different meaning? Thanks.

Comment: @NikolayKomolov First: we say reasons **for** something, not **of**. Second: You may encounter *reasons for X* without an article, but this should be avoided: it leaves the reader wondering whether you are listing *all* the reasons (which should be expressed as ***the** reasons for X*) or just *some* of them (which should be expressed as ***Some of the** reasons for X*), so it comes off as evasive.